# Find method by RequestMapping value(url) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to find which method is triggered on my website when I open some url or to get return of that method (Something like AJAX, but in Java/Spring). I have that url in String.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Finding which method is triggered"*? You can simply use a `Logger` in your application and it will give you all the activity with the `TimeStamp` or else you can start returning some `HTML` from your method indicating the name of that method or something which will then be rendered on your browser.

Comment: I wanna to check if my RequestMapping method return exception and prevent redirecting. For example, I have a link on my page and I want instead of receiving "Access Denied", 404 and similar to stay on current page and show some notification.

Comment: use model view in your controller and catch your exception and if it throws exception redirect or call your current view again.